# Recreate Azure SQL Database before E2E test

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database, end-to-end, appveyor

I have an application with an Azure SQL Server. I have a test environment where I deploy the app for end to end testing. I want to reset the database to a certain state before the tests. I have a bacpac file with that state. My goal is to do this with a ci tool (appveyor). I am aware that I can drop the entire database with azure powershell api. Should I drop the database or should I empty it? Or am I thinking this totally wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Powershell to restore the BACPAC before the tests and drop the database after the tests. An example is available on Azure docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/scripts/sql-database-import-from-bacpac-powershell

An option that will probably execute faster, is to directlry run T-SQL against the database to setup your initial state before the tests and empty the database after the tests.

However, doing a full BACPAC restore and drop out is much easier to setup in such a way that you can run multiple testruns in parallel as it is not relying on a pre-existent database that it is claiming for the duration of the run.

Edit: Changed link to en-us instead of nl-nl

Comment: Thanks for the example link! (I had to remove the dutch translation in the URL because I speak Swedish/English). I will go for drop the entire database because its probably much easier even though it slower.

Comment: Also the approach I would recommend, since it would allow you to scale-out your testruns

Comment: database initial state setup is actually part of e2e testing, the same applies to use cases data setup and post data verification, have you tried endly: https://github.com/viant/endly/

Answer (score 0):

Another option is you run Azure database as docker service, this may simplify your initial databse setup.